# Misunderstanding of time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

**My question** 
I am currently learning time complexity and I was presented with the following example to solve the time complexity:

```
sum=0
for j=1 to 12
    add = add + figures[j]
average = add/12
print average

for x=12 to n-1{
 total = total - figures[x-11] + figures[x+1]
 average=total/12
 print average 
}
```

My answer: time complexity = n
Explanation/Thought Process: 
The first loop is executed 12 times and The second loop is executed n-12 times. I believe the time complexity is 'n' because n-12+12=n and the loops are not nested.

Teacher's answer: time complexity = 2n
I am not sure why though. Any help in understanding would be great!

Also, Is there a method to helping realize other common complexities?

For Example:

1. n
2. log n
3. n log n
4. n2 (power to two)
5. n3 (power to three)
6. 2n (power to n)

Comment: `j=1 to 12` can be regarded as constant time. So the running time is always O(n) (big oh of n)

Comment: So was my answer correct that it should be 'n'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes his answer is correct. The time complexity will be 2n.

In this sample, the for loop will run for some value n. Whether it runs from 1 to 12 or 1 to 1000 does not matter because whatever that value n is, the for loop will end execution once it reaches its limit, n.

The 2 in his answer, time complexity = 2n, comes from the fact that there are two for loops that will be executed for this sample is done executing.

Check this [article](https://www.interviewcake.com/article/java/big-o-notation-time-and-space-complexity) out. It provides some pretty straight forward explanations

Comment: Thank you for the article. Sorry just let me get this straight so if there was 3 different not nested for loops it would be 3n?

Comment: Why would you consider the first loop as O(n)?

Comment: @user7 take a look at that article link

Comment: I agree it is O(2n) (which is O(n)) if the first for loop's termination condition was expressed as a function of `n`. But it is not the case. Here it is equivalent to having 12 different expressions one in each line

Answer (score 3):

I had a very interesting discussion with my professor once on this same topic. I worked for a really cool company that did thermal modelling with beowulf clusters. Very, very computationally intensive. My professor said if I could take a function from `4n^2` to `2n^2` my boss would not be happy. But if I could take it from `4n^2` to `4n` he would be happy. I raised my hand, saying if I could cut the time in half my boss would be very, very happy with that. She said no, he'd only be happy with an order of magnitude improvement - linear improvements in the same order of magnitude are irrelevant.

I called my boss that day. He said if I could cut the runtime in half, he'd fly me home, double my pay, and buy me steak dinners for a year.

Sometimes it matters to know what the coefficients are. Other times it doesn't. So you're absolutely right that when dealing with the order of complexity of these code snippets, `4n` or `10000n` or `n` are all the same - they are `O(n)`.

By the way, he may be using `2n` instead of `n` because there are two lookups in the second loop, while the first loop (which is run a constant number of times) has only 1 lookup.

So if he says "Time complexity is 2n" he's correct. If he says "Time complexity is O(2n)" he is incorrect - O(...) means something very specific, and does not have coefficients.

Comment: So at the end of the day, having 2n or n doesn't matter in regards to this question. And why would O(2n) be wrong? O() is used to represent time complexity. Isn't 2n or n representing time complexity?

Comment: Your response added a very import detail that I overlooked, the number of look ups in the second for loop. For a further development of my understanding, have you seen that before? Where the number of operations (in this case, two look up operations) allow the coefficient to stick? @corsiKa

Comment: @JakeJames Using Big O notation means something very specific. There are no constants in Big O notation. That does not mean all analysis of time complexity ignores those constants. It just mean that Big O ignores those constants.

Comment: @corsiKa Thank you. Just a point: if you follow this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aj59L-_7V70 and jump to exactly 2:28 you will see the exact same problem and answered exactly the same, however, she did converted O(2n) to -> O(n). Was that correct? Thanks

Comment: @JakeJames Yes because it is O(2n). Big O notation is a formal function. It has strict, formally defined inputs and outputs. That does not mean that all attempts to measure time complexity use those same formal methods.